# How should LLVM Function clones be cleaned up?

Tags: llvm

I have an LLVM pass that traverses input IR code and performs analysis on called functions. My analysis function signature is `functionTracer(const Function* pFunc)` and I call it on a `CallInst`'s `getCalledFunction()`.

At the start of my analysis function I create a copy of the passed in function that I  manipulate during the analysis:

```
Function* pFunctionToAnalyze = CloneFunction(pFunction,VMap,false);
```

I have a C++ main that calls a function `f2(int i)`:

```
int main(){
    int a = 3;
    int b = f2(a);
    int c = f2(b);
}
```

I turn this code into IR and submit to my pass. My code appears to execute and perform the manipulations I want but I get the following error output:

```
While deleting: i32 (i32)* %_Z2f2i
Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed:  %call1 = call i32 @_Z2f2i(i32 %1)
Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed:  %call = call i32 @_Z2f2i(i32 %0)
module: /home/src/extern/llvm/llvm-3.7.0.src/lib/IR/Value.cpp:82: 
virtual llvm::Value::~Value(): Assertion `use_empty() && "Uses remain when a value is destroyed!"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Do I need to perform manual clean up of the Cloned function, `pFunctionToAnalyze`, at the end of my analysis function to remove Uses before returning? Is there a better way to copy function contents for analysis that may modify it?

Comment: How do you delete your functions?

Comment: I think that is the core of my question - I do not know the proper way to delete them.

Comment: Ok let me be a little bit more precise. What have you tried so far to delete a function?

Comment: I was assuming that it was deleted once it passed out of scope: I call the analysis function, create the function copy, iterate over its instructions and hack away, then return from my analysis function. My guess is the pointer `pFunctionToAnalyze` needs to be explicitly destroyed before returning from the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example on that in lib/Transforms/IPO/PartialInlining.cpp

```
  // Clone the function, so that we can hack away on it.
  ValueToValueMapTy VMap;
  Function* duplicateFunction = CloneFunction(F, VMap,
                                              /*ModuleLevelChanges=*/false);
```

And in the end of the pass:

```
duplicateFunction->replaceAllUsesWith(F);
duplicateFunction->eraseFromParent();
```

Isn't that what fixes your problem?

Comment: My code analyzes a single function by copying it, then iterating over all instructions: 
`for(inst_iterator pInstr = inst_begin(pFunctionToAnalyze), pEnd = inst_end(pFunctionToAnalyze); pInstr != pEnd; ++pInstr)`

I added the `replaceAllUsesWith(pFunction)` and `eraseFromParent()` function calls after the for loop and it seg faults.

Comment: Do you also call pFunction->replaceAllUsesWith(pFunctionToAnalyze) before your pass?

Comment: When I add that in before the pass the seg fault goes away, but the original error remains. One non-standard complication is that my analysis handles recursion. Adding in the addition to the parent, etc. I get an infinite loop. I need to investigate some more. I still do no understand why the original function is somehow linked to the clone. I must be missing something subtle in the `CloneFunction` code. I will keep investigating my analysis structure. Regardless, I believe your answer is correct - I have an edge case or faulty logic.